# Plancks law of blackbody radiation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation, blackbody

I am going to plot this curve with wave length:

$$
I(f)df =  \frac{2 \pi  h}{ c^{2} } \cdot  f^{3} \cdot  \frac{1}{ e^{ \frac{h f}{kT}-1 } }  df
$$

converting:

$$
 I( \lambda )d \lambda =  \frac{2 \pi h  c^{2}  }{   \lambda ^{5} } \cdot  \frac{1}{ e^{ \frac{hc}{ \lambda kT} } -1}d \lambda 
$$

How am I supposed to think about the axis if I plot it in MatLab. I get:

$$
 Y-axis: \frac{J}{m^{3}s}
$$

$$
 X-axis:  /m
$$

When I try to make this equation in MatLAb I just ignore the $d\lambda$.
And that doesn't feel right.

Can someone please enlighten me on how to tackle this one.
How shall deal with the $d\lambda$ term when I want to plot it.

Answer (score 2):

Your function $I(\lambda,T)$ is the [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance). It's the intensity per steradian per square meter **per unit wavelength**. To get the total intensity radiated per steradian per square meter over all wavelengths between $\lambda$ and $\lambda + d\lambda$ you multiply it by $d\lambda$, as you've done in your second equation (strictly speaking you integrate $I$ from $\lambda$ to $\lambda + d\lambda$).

So just go ahead and plot $I(\lambda,T)$, but remember exactly what it is that you're plotting - it isn't the intensity of the radiation it's the intensity per unit wavelength.

Comment: Sometimes I see 2hc^2 instead of 2*pi*h*c^2. Otherwise they look the same. What is the difference?